# Reformat external Date-Format to unix-timestamp / ee-compatible format

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have a date-field where I get some raw data from another system (I have no control over the export of the other system) … the date is published in the following format:

```
2010-10-26T07:11:18Z
```

Is there a way to easily convert this format into a unix-timestamp/ee-compatible format?

I've tried `{exp:query sql="SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP('col_id_22') AS unixtime FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE entry_id = {entry_id}"}{unixtime}{/exp:query}` but this does not work (I guess because of the `T` and `Z` in the raw data?

Comment: Could you use [Low Replace](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-replace) to format the date - using regex - into the correct format?

Comment: Are you looking to use this on the front-end or back-end?

Comment: @DerekHogue: Well, we could change the format while importing (backend) or while displaying (Frontend).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If displaying, one option could be to use the Nice Date plugin by low http://gotolow.com/addons/low-nice-date/docs which will displays date given a formatting.

Comment: Great! Didn't knew that plugin (and somehow oversaw on devot-ee). Thx Erwin!